# iptables limit the number of connections in the system for both ipv4 ipv6

Tags: networking, iptables, ipv6, ipv4

A connection is a 5 tuple (ip src/dst, port src/dst, protocol).
What about different connections between ipv4 and ipv6?

If I define the `iptables` rule:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m connlimit --connlimit-above 50 -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
```

It limits the tcp connections to 50.

What about ipv6 tcp connections? should I write also

```
ip6tables -A INPUT -p tcp -m connlimit --connlimit-above 50 -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
```

?

Does it mean that I can have 100 tcp connections overall? (50 ipv4 50 ipv6) ?

How does it work?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have 50 of each connections, since `iptables` will handle only ipv4 and `ip6tables` will deal with ipv6 connections. They will not "sum" up, because they are managed by different tools on each protocol version.

Will `nftables`, the "new firewall" be able to deal with both protocols summing up everything? No. You will have the "same tool"(`nft` binary) to deal with protocols independently using the `rule` keyword: `nft add rule ip6 ...` and `nft add rule ip ...`

As pointed out in the comments, the [nft_connlimit](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/log/net/netfilter/nft_connlimit.c) extension was recently added to Linux 4.18, allowing you to count sum `ipv4` and `ipv6` if you use the reserved word `inet` while creating rules.

**Related Stuff:**

- [Serverfault: How do you set a max connection limit with nftables?](https://serverfault.com/q/934092/122772)

Comment: Now the feature has been implemented with nftables, actually using the family `inet` instead of just `ip` or just `ip6` will use the combined count of IPv4 and IPv6 connections retrieved from conntrack. See my related answer on SF there: [How do you set a max connection limit with nftables?](https://serverfault.com/a/939910/217515)

Comment: Thanks for the info A.B. Added to the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that means you can have 50+50 connections.